# Nvida crashes after system update... Driver is no longer available

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia

I got a black screen after a system update and I can't seem to find the video driver anymore. The driver was `nvidia-304xx` for my `GeForce 7900 glx` graphics card. I wonder which driver is now supported by this card.

Comment: looks like the 304 drivers are [no longer supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Unsupported_drivers)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nvidia](https://www.geforce.com/drivers) the only proprietary driver version available for the Nvidia GeForce 7900GLX is indeed version 304.xx.

As commented above by @quixotic, [ArchLinux no longer supports 304.xx](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Unsupported_drivers). So, from now on, the open source `nouveau` is your only option. Or replace the card with a newer card supported at least by the version 340.xx which is Nvidia's driver for legacy-yet-not-entirelly-obsolete cards.